# How to interpret the following error in Lean?

Tags: types, lean, theorem

I have the following code:

```
example (x y : ℕ):
    (x + y) * (x+y ) = x*x + y*x + x*y +y*y
    :=
    have s₀:(x+y)*(x+y) = (x+y)*x + (x+y)*y, 
        from nat.left_distrib (x+y) x y ,
    have s₁: (x+y)*x = x*x + y*x,
        from nat.right_distrib x y x,
    have s₂: (x+y)*y = x*y + y*y,
        from nat.right_distrib x y y,
    have s₃: (x+y)*(x+y) = x*x + y*x + (x+y)*y, 
        from s₁ ▸ s₀, 
    show   (x + y) * (x+y ) = x*x + y*x + x*y +y*y , 
        from 
        (@eq.subst ℕ  (λ T:ℕ , (x+y)*(x+y) = x*x + y*x + T ) 
        ( (x+y)*y ) (x*y + y*y) ) (s₂)  (s₃)
```

The problem seems to be in the last step (in show), the compiler tells me:

```
term
  s₂ ▸ s₃
has type
  (λ (T : ℕ), (x + y) * (x + y) = x * x + y * x + T) (x * y + y * y)
but is expected to have type
  (x + y) * (x + y) = x * x + y * x + x * y + y * y
```

I do not understand. Aren't both types the same?

Comment: they'll associate slighly different; if you go into tactic mode and `dsimp` at `s₂ \t s₃`, you'll see that

Comment: (A+B)+(C+D) isn't ((A+B)+C)+D, I guess this is the issue.

Comment: For those interested in Proof Assistants, there is a new proposed SE site [ProofAssistants](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126242/proof-assistants?referrer=Njg4YTJmMjYwOTIxNjdkNGEyMmZkNzE0Y2M4YmFhOTY3OWVmNDUwNWM3ZmFlMjYwYTRiYzZiZWY1ODg5ZjdiMqfBIyhShuHO9QbGuJfVwOYRvfVgPfbJQrn2UOFTeOe-0)